# Refresh image every day automatically

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I need to show some images periodically in a Windows form application. The source of the image is a fixed URL link. The image in the link is updated every day automatically. What I need is to make my application have the ability to refresh the image every day automatically. How can I do this in `C++/CLI` or `C#`?  I would like to mention also that I have to pass through a proxy IP & port in order to access the Internet (the link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming its a picturebox:

```
private void PopulatePictureBox()
{
 ImageList images = new ImageList();
 images.Images.Add(LoadImage("http://www.website.com/123.jpg"));
 picbox.Image = imagelst.Images[0];
}
```

Assuming its a listView control:

```
private void PopulateListView()
{
    ImageList images = new ImageList();
    images.Images.Add(LoadImage("http://www.website.com/123.jpg"));
    images.Images.Add(LoadImage("http://www.website.com/456.jpg"));

    listView1.SmallImageList = images;
    listView1.Items.Add("An item", 0);
    listView1.Items.Add("Another item item", 1);
}
```

This the function to get the image from the web:

```
private Image LoadImage(string url)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest request =
        System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);

    System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    System.IO.Stream responseStream =
        response.GetResponseStream();

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(responseStream);

    responseStream.Dispose();

    return bmp;
}
```

Not sure if you wish to save the picture to disk, I'll leave that option up to you.

Comment: thanks for your organized clear code, but what If I have to pass through proxy before accessing the link and also how can I make it to check every day to refresh, I will be using image box.

Comment: The easiest way would be to setup a Scheduled task to run daily that downloads the image and saves it to a share location. Then set the `picturebox.Image = "\\san\DailyImages\2012-9-12.jpg";`. Going through the proxy shouldn't matter, let us know if it does

Answer (score 1):

Simply download the image from URL using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) or [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Then use it in whatever way you want. Both have properties related to Proxy. Set those accordingly and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a routine which saves last refresh date, and compare this once an hour with current Time for example like:

```
current.subtract(lastUpdated).Days > 1
```